# Can I draw a small arrow from a word to a space-gap on the same line?

Tags: arrows, text-decorations, inline

I want to illustrate that the `const` in the following line can also be moved one word to the right. Maybe I can underline the const and draw a slim **arced arrow pointing to the next gap**?

```
const int * val
-----___-^
```

The TeX source is this:

```
\begin{auflistung} % itemize
  \itm{} % item
  \mono{\fett{const int} * val}
%...
\end{auflistung}
```

where `auflistung` serves as an itemize environment, `itm` as an item, `mono` as typewriter-tpye, and `fett` as bold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be done using [`pst-node`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node) - the node connection extension of [`pstricks`](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). Here are a couple of examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-node
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \texttt{\textbf{\rnode{A}{const} int}\rnode{B}{\strut\ }* val}
    \ncbar[nodesep=2pt,linewidth=0.5pt,angle=90]{->}{A}{B}

  \item \texttt{\textbf{\rnode{C}{const} int}\rnode{D}{\phantom{c}}* val}
    \nccurve[nodesep=2pt,linewidth=0.5pt,angleA=60,angleB=120]{->}{C}{D}

  \item \texttt{\textbf{\rnode{E}{const} int}\rlap{\rnode{F}{\phantom{oo}}} * val}
    \ncarc[nodesep=2pt,linewidth=0.5pt,arcangle=45]{->}{E}{F}

  \item \texttt{\textbf{\rnode{G}{const} int}\rnode{H}{\phantom{t}}* val}
    \ncdiag[nodesep=2pt,linewidth=0.5pt,arm=.3,linearc=.2,angle=90]{->}{G}{H}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrows used in code]

Your compilation sequence is either `latex` -> `dvips` (-> `ps2pdf`) or `xelatex`. Modifications to the above code could include arrows/arcs spanning below the code (rather than above), colour, line style and width changes and many more. Read the [`pst-node` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-node/pst-node-doc.pdf) or the [`pstricks` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf) (Chapter **VII Nodes and Node Connections**) for more information.

Comment: Beautiful! I had `pst-node` already installed on my system, so I used it. I have to deliver a `.ps` file, so I should be safe there, I guess. Currently I use `ps2pdf` and that works, too. I decided on `\nccurve[linecolor=lightgray,nodesep=1pt,linewidth=0.5pt,angleA=40,angleB=140]{->}{D}{W}`

Comment: Also very good the hint about `\phantom` --- line 2 and line 3 --- I would not have known how to make perfectly matching spaces.

Answer (score 8):

You could use TikZ for this.

Somewhere at the start of the document, issue

```
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        remember picture,   % Make nodes available to all TikZ pictures
        inner xsep=0pt, % Remove horizontal padding
        inner ysep=1pt, % Set small vertical padding
        baseline,       % Align TikZ pictures at the baseline
        every node/.style={
            anchor=base % Align all nodes at the baseline
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can replace the word `const` with `\tikz \node (a) {const};` and the space between `int` and `*` with `\tikz \node  (b) {\hphantom{ }};`, creating two nodes `(a)` and `(b)` that can then be linked using `\tikz [overlay] \draw [red,->]  (a.south) to [bend right=70]  (b.south);`, yielding

[image]

Here's the complete document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        remember picture,   % Make nodes available to all TikZ pictures
        inner xsep=0pt, % Remove horizontal padding
        inner ysep=1pt, % Set small vertical padding
        baseline,       % Align TikZ pictures at the baseline
        every node/.style={
            anchor=base % Align all nodes at the baseline
        }
    }
}


\begin{itemize} % itemize
  \item{} % item
  \texttt{\tikz \node [anchor=base]  (a) {const}; int\tikz \node  (b) {\hphantom{ }};* val}
    \tikz [overlay] \draw [red,->]  (a.south) to [bend right=70]  (b.south);
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hehe, I also had TikZ in mind, but my solution was much less elegant. Fortunately one is informed about new answers being posted while typing ;)

Comment: I think I stumbled over `tikz` once. I have not used it, yet.

Comment: @jack, I use your code and compile it with `xelatex` or `pdftexify` twice, there is an error **!missing \endcsname inserted**. I ignore the error, then I can get your outcome. Hoe to solve it? thanks.

Comment: Now, 3 years later, that I wanted implement something similar. By now I am much more familiar with tikz and decided to go with your solution. And it works very well, thank you.