# How can I join two letters with an arrow?

Tags: diagrams

I have to write a manual for a game. The explanations include visuals like:

[image]

In short, I will need a circle (not absolute must, a square will also do) around two letters, and an arrow from letter 1 to letter 2. (Sometimes it will be anticlockwise.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Tikz](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)  and its `remember picture` property. Here is just a starting point for you base on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29619/22492) answer by [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake). You can of course start to play with the parameters (e.g. bending!) to fine tune the results for your taste.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        remember picture,   % Make nodes available to all TikZ pictures
        inner xsep=0pt, % Remove horizontal padding
        inner ysep=1pt, % Set small vertical padding
        baseline,       % Align TikZ pictures at the baseline
        every node/.style={
            anchor=base % Align all nodes at the baseline
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}

b\tikz \node[circle, thin,draw](a) {e};n\tikz \node[circle, thin,draw](b) {e};dict
 \tikz [overlay] \draw [->]  (a.north) to [bend right=-70]  (b.north);   
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect the OP will be doing this often. Can you package the code in a macro so that something like (say) `\circles{benedict}{e}{e}` connects the two e's?

Comment: @EthanBolker, You are indeed right and I was going to! The problem is, it can be very tricky. For example, how about `\circles{comprehensive}{e}{e}`? A workaround however, would be something in the lines of `\circles{benedict}{2}{4}`. I was going to and I still am going to try to convert it to macro but write now I'm on LaTeX-Less machine. I will try something tomorrow `:)`