# Arrow under interval

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

How to produce an arrow under an interval in order to indicate that the two elements may have to be reversed?

For instance I would like to typeset `[x, y]` with a double-headed arrow between `x` and `y`.

Here is a sketch of the desire output:

[image: sketch]

I am using AMS packages.

Comment: Could you please show a sketch of the desired output? Some more background information on where / in which context or environment you want to use it, might also be helpful.

Comment: I added a sketch

Comment: (Maybe) Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183511 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29618.

Comment: Is the question still open? (there are answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged `tikz-arrows`, I am wondering if you are looking for something like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\[ [\tikzmarknode{x}{x},\tikzmarknode{y}{y}]\qquad 
[\tikzmarknode{Sn}{S_n},\tikzmarknode{Sn+1}{S_{n+1}}]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,>={Stealth[bend]}]
\draw[<->] (x.south|-y.south) to[out=-70,in=-110] (y.south);
\draw[<->] (Sn.south|-Sn+1.south) to[out=-70,in=-110] (Sn+1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is a bit verbose but it does the job

Answer (score 3):

Here are  some possibilities with the curved arrows of `mathabx`, without having to load the package, and  `\underset/ _overset` or with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
 <-6> mathb5 
 <6-7> mathb6 
 <7-8> mathb7 
 <8-9> mathb8 
 <9-10> mathb9 
 <10-12> mathb10 
 <12-> mathb12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxcurvearrowleft}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\abxcurvearrowright}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowleftright}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowbotleft}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowbotright}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\curvearrowbotleftright}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"F5}


\begin{document}

\[ [ \underset{\curvearrowbotleftright}{a, b}] \qquad [ \overset{\curvearrowleftright}{a, b}]\qquad [ \overset{\abxcurvearrowleft}{ \underset{\curvearrowbotright}{a, b}}] \]%

\setstackgap{S}{1pt}%
\setstackgap{L}{7pt}
\[\stackMath [ \Shortunderstack{a, b\\\curvearrowbotleftright}] \qquad [ \Shortstack{\curvearrowleftright\\a, \vphantom{i}\smash[t]{b}}]\qquad [ \Vectorstack{\abxcurvearrowleft\\ a, b \\ \curvearrowbotright}]\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `\underset` from `amsmath` and `\longleftrightarrow`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\underset{\longleftrightarrow}{[x,y]}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you think that this arrow is too long, you might use the normal `\leftrightarrow`:

```latex
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\underset{\leftrightarrow}{[x,y]}$
\end{document}
```

[image]